# Seamless Procedural Texture in Polar Coordinates

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, coordinates

I've written a Cycles node tree to convert rectangular (X,Y) to polar coordinates (R,theta) as the basis for a procedural texture with radial symmetry.

However, there is a seam in the texture where theta jumps in value (-pi -> pi or 0 -> 2pi).

What are some of the techniques for eliminating this seam? I have found one method that uses a blended overlap region. Are there others?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/45169/7777

Comment: That's useful for textures with regularity. Thank you for including the details of the node groups for the cylindrical and spherical projections. I will compare them to the node groups I created.

I plan to use Noise, Voronoi, or Musgrave textures that do not repeat like the chevron in your solution. I expect the discontinuity at -pi (or 2pi) will be visible.

Comment: Yes, when the texture is not tiled you will have a seam.

Comment: I am curious as if you have found a solution to this issue...

Comment: @astrogeek More specifically, would you mind showing us how you achieved the blended overlap region or linking the solution you found? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @VilkoL I haven't gotten back to this issue yet. I'm currently hiding the seam by using a texture with a really large scale (i.e. small-scale features) so the seam is largely mixed in among the many variations in the texture.

I found this wonderful page http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/edgeblend/ and intended to use his algorithm. The middle-to-last part of the page gets into the details.

Comment: Something like this may help : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119564/29586

Comment: @ Rich, that page poses a great solution. Thanks for the heads-up so many years after my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Sine and cosine pair to bend an axis into a loop.

I'm using a sphere to represent to polar coordinates but the math applies regardless.

This will use up 2 axes of your procedural texture for the Theta component.

[image: sphere with seamless tiling at its UV sphere]

Important to have the theta properly in radians. here it's done by, mutiplying it by 2π.