# How do I have a procedural texture follow the surface of a mesh?

Tags: materials, node-editor, procedural

I am trying to texture a high poly sculpted model, making UV unwrapping impractical. The object is a spiral horn. The texture has rows of color that I want to follow the spiral. Is This possible? I've tried changing to polar coordinates, like in this example [How do I make a procedural swirl texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68947/how-do-i-make-a-procedural-swirl-texture)
But I can't seem to get that to work.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It seems to work fine if you unwrap your object with the *Follow Active Quads* option (select all your faces in *Edit* mode, then one last face then <kbd>U</kbd>), now your unwrap is completely square and your texture will follow along. Then create this nodes chain: *Texture Coordinate* (*UV* output) > *Mappin*g (play with the *Rotation* angle) > *Texture* > etc.

[image]

Comment: I was hoping not to have to retopo it and keep the sculpted details. Right now there are no quads.

Comment: ok so I'm not sure but maybe you have no other choice but to retopo, bake the details and use the bump map as a displacement?