# Can a procedural texture follow the x y z orientation of vertices or do I need to UV unwrap?

Tags: mesh, uv, shaders, geometry, procedural

So lets say:

I want to avoid seams on my model.
I'm to lazy to UV unwrap.
I want to keep my mesh joined.

**Would it be possible to create a procedural material that follows the xyz orientation of a vertex or a vertex group?**

The first screenshot is what I have and the 2nd one is what I want to achieve in terms of, the material following the xyz orientation. It has seams now which ruins the procedural aspect of it.

I found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/175278/how-do-i-have-a-procedural-texture-follow-the-surface-of-a-mesh) but its not really what I want need, but goes in a similair direction.

[image: without uv's]

[image: with terrible smart uv's]

I hope this is clear.

Hope I didn't violate any rules.
First post, thanks in advance,

Paul

Comment: Hello :). If you split the table into individual planks, then Object coordinates should give you such result.

Comment: You can also unwrap automatically, with *UV > Smart UV project*. Works really well for this type of geometry.

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/113922/19156

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the answers. Yes, the second image is Smart UV projected, but I dont want to have seems. Splitting in individual planks indeed works, but thats what i wanted to avoid :)