# How to set up Vector for a radial Voronoi Texture without a Texture Seam

Tags: shaders, texture-coordinates, vector

does anybody know of a way to make a similar looking texture that scales from the centre outwards without having a seam *(see picture)*?

[image: Vector Setup for my Voronoi Texture]

[image: What i want to avoid if possible]

anything that produces a texture of some kind of cones that originate from the centre would work in my case.

any help or Ideas would be greatly appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102262/29586

Comment: Hi! ... 'Some kind of cones'  would pack a sphere, but wouldn't pack a cylinder. There would be gaps .. are those what you want?

Comment: @RobinBetts my goal is a physicaly accurate knot for a wood texture that i am making. what i search are "dots" (or branches) that get larger, the further they are from the centre, like a real tree does.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you need, something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge7IJ.png?

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119564/29586 for discussion around mapping radially without a seam.

Comment: @RichSedman this seems like what i searched for, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Got it working now.

[image: new node setup]

did it like @RichSedman post instructed and changed some things, now it looks like this:

[image: new texture]

compared to the old one:

[image: old]

now i wont get my knots cut in half where the texture used to have a seam:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how to [set musgrave to get something periodic?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/119564/29586), you can map your texture radially around a cylinder using a material such as the following :

[image: material and result]

Here the coordinates are constructed based on the Radial coordinate (which varies between 0.0 and 1.0 for around the circumference) and the Z coordinate (for along the cylinder length).

The radial gradient (0.0 to 1.0) is multiplied by `2*pi` and the X and Y coordinates generated using Sine and Cosine functions - such that the 0.0 to 1.0 gradient represents a full rotation, so that it matches up at the seam (ie, 0 degrees matches to 360 degrees around the circumference).